# How to Check if an Paired Bluetooth device is a Printer or a Scanner (Android)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I hope can help me,
I am developing an Android App, that require to connect with Bluetooth devices, like Scanner and Printer, currently I can list all Paired devices, but i want to know if the paired device is a Printer, Scanner, Mobile, etc.

There is some way to know the kind of bluetooth device paired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short,

Yes you can. You
can do this by using the [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) of the device. If you know the UUID of a device you can match them up from the reported UUID and know which paired device is what.

Something like this:

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

Method getUuidsMethod = BluetoothAdapter.class.getDeclaredMethod("getUuids", null);

ParcelUuid[] uuids = (ParcelUuid[]) getUuidsMethod.invoke(adapter, null);
```

Now simply compare the retrieved UUID to the devices known UUID( online or on the box).

If they are a match you know what device it is.

**Note:** most common UUID (scanners, printers, Mice) have the generic UUID `0001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`

Read about the [getUUID()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getUuids%28%29) method, [paracable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelUuid.html) method , [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) java class and finally [Java.util.UUID.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Comment: Thanks, i found another way to do it, but it will be useful

Comment: Well look because i just want to filter printer paired devices, i use the BluetoothClass of the device, so then i filter the getMajorDeviceClass() with all devices that are 1536 (Imaging) and 1280 (Peripherical), so it fix my problem, but thanks for your answer, will help me maybe later

Comment: Gotcha. it is much less application specific.

Comment: Well, i just dont want to filter devices based on specific data, because it could change later, the majordeviceclass is general and universal for devices and type of them, thats was the reason i do of this way.

Comment: UUIDS don't change ever. It is hardware specific thats why its a universal identifier. Plus changing it is a security risk and therefore against bluetooth protocol.

Comment: i get it, it sounds a nice way to do, probably i will change my code, thanks man, cheers!

Comment: @MaxPinto so what is the solution?

Comment: @MaxPinto getMajorDeviceClass is not always best solution. At least my rongta-200 printer is always returnig UNCATEGORIZED code.

Answer (score 9):

Accepted answer is too generic, because UUID 0001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB assert that device has serial port capabilites, and many not printer devices has this kind of UUID.

You should evalute full CoD, at this [link](http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/software/bluetooth_class_of_device-service_generator.html) you can extract exact bit mask for serivice you need to recognize, that for a printer is :

`0b000001000000011010000000`

with this you can do a mask on full device CoD as:

```java
private static boolean isAPrinter(BluetoothDevice device){
    int printerMask = 0b000001000000011010000000;
    int fullCod = device.getBluetoothClass().hashCode();
    Log.d(TAG, "FULL COD: " + fullCod);
    Log.d(TAG, "MASK RESULT " + (fullCod & printerMask));
    return (fullCod & printerMask) == printerMask;
}
```

Comment: How to recognize if it's a barcode scanner with such mask? Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

I have one idea, it may help you.

```
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
{
    String deviceBTMajorClass = getBTMajorDeviceClass(device.getBluetoothClass().getMajorDeviceClass());
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "deviceBTMajorClass"+deviceBTMajorClass);
    //btArrayAdapter.add(deviceBTName + "\n"+ deviceBTMajorClass);
    data.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
}

private String getBTMajorDeviceClass(int major) {
    switch (major) {
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.AUDIO_VIDEO:
            return "AUDIO_VIDEO";
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.COMPUTER:
            return "COMPUTER";
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.HEALTH:
            return "HEALTH";
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.IMAGING:
            return "IMAGING";
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.MISC:
            return "MISC";
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.NETWORKING:
            return "NETWORKING";
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.PERIPHERAL:
            return "PERIPHERAL";
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.PHONE:
            return "PHONE";
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.TOY:
            return "TOY";
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.UNCATEGORIZED:
            return "UNCATEGORIZED";
        case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.WEARABLE:
            return "AUDIO_VIDEO";`enter code here`
        default:
            return "unknown!";
    }
}
```