# Filter bonded device in bluetooth android

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am building a Health application in which blood pressure monitor is used. I already paired so many BLE devices. I want to filter only particular device like Blood Pressure Monitor. I also did this in scan filter through like this

**BloodPressurePairViewModel.kt**

```
class BloodPressurePairViewModel : ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        private const val SCAN_PERIOD: Long = 10000 // For 1 minute scan
        private const val UUID_MASK_STRING = "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF"
        private const val BLUETOOTH_PRESSURE_128_STRING = "00001810-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
        private const val BLUETOOTH_PRESSURE_MEASUREMENT_128_STRING = "00002A35-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
    }

    var bluetoothLeScanner: BluetoothLeScanner? = null
    var isBluetoothEnabled by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set
    val mLeDevices: MutableStateFlow<List<ScanResult>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
    var scanning: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(true)
        private set
    private val leScanCallback: ScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
            if (!mLeDevices.value.equals(result)) {
                if (result.device?.name != null) {
                    if (checkDuplicateScanResult(mLeDevices.value, result)) {
                        mLeDevices.value += result
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onBatchScanResults(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results)
            logE("onBatchScanResults >> $results")
        }

        override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode)
            logE("onScanFailed >> $errorCode")
        }
    }

    fun setBluetoothEnable(newValue: Boolean) {
        isBluetoothEnabled = newValue
    }

    fun startScan() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(SCAN_PERIOD)
            scanning.value = false
            bluetoothLeScanner?.startScan(scanFilters(), ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER).build(), leScanCallback)
        }
    }

    private fun scanFilters(): MutableList<ScanFilter> {
        val scanFilterList = mutableListOf<ScanFilter>()
        val parcelUuidMask = ParcelUuid.fromString(UUID_MASK_STRING)
        val listItem = listOf(BLUETOOTH_PRESSURE_128_STRING, BLUETOOTH_PRESSURE_MEASUREMENT_128_STRING)
        listItem.forEach {
            val scanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(it), parcelUuidMask).build()
            scanFilterList.add(scanFilter)
        }
        return scanFilterList
    }

    fun stopScan() {
        bluetoothLeScanner?.stopScan(leScanCallback)
    }

    private fun checkDuplicateScanResult(value: List<ScanResult>, result: ScanResult): Boolean {
        val checkDevice = value.count { it.device == result.device }
        return checkDevice < 1
    }
}
```

I used `scanFilters()` to find particular type of device like BPM. Now I want to filter according to my 128 bit string in my bonded device. I tried this piece of code from this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27302060/18958467) but it didn't work.  I tried this piece of code

```
val getUuidsMethod: Method = BluetoothAdapter::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("getUuids", null)
val uuids = getUuidsMethod.invoke(bluetoothAdapter, null)
```

but it giving me error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: parameter type is null
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
                                                                                                        at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.composables.PairScreenState.getPairedDevice(BloodPressurePairScreen.kt:176)
                                                                                                        at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.composables.PairScreenState.<init>(BloodPressurePairScreen.kt:156)
                                                                                                        at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.composables.BloodPressurePairScreenKt.rememberPairScreenState(BloodPressurePairScreen.kt:118)
                                                                                                        at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.composables.BloodPressurePairScreenKt.BluetoothPairContentStateful(BloodPressurePairScreen.kt:66)
                                                                                                        at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.composables.BloodPressurePairScreenKt.BluetoothPairContent(BloodPressurePairScreen.kt:52)
                                                                                                        at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.composables.BluetoothRequestScreenKt$BluetoothRequestContent$1.invoke(BluetoothRequestScreen.kt:39)
                                                                                                        at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.composables.BluetoothRequestScreenKt$BluetoothRequestContent$1.invoke(BluetoothRequestScreen.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
```

Can you guys help me on this?

Comment: I do not think the linked approach will work for you.  Firstly it references a private API from six years ago which may not exist anymore in modern Android versions.  Secondly, the UUIDs that the private api fetches are the device class UUIDs which you do not want and not the GATT service UUIDs  which you do want.

Comment: Sure no problem. Thanks a million for your time.